# Count all files in all folders/subfolders with Python

Tags: python, linux, file, count

Which is the **most efficient way** to count all files in all folders and subfolders in Python? I want to use this on Linux systems.

Example output:

> (Path files)
>
> / 2
>
> /bin 100
>
> /boot 20
>
> /boot/efi/EFI/redhat 1
>
> ....
>
> /root 34
>
> ....

Paths without a file should be ignored.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think could be a way to do it? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `os.walk()`;

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/some/path'):
    if files:
        print('{0} {1}'.format(root, len(files)))
```

Note that this will also include hidden files, i.e. those that begin with a dot (`.`).

Comment: I also want the hidden files. Thats not a problem. But I get this error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print('{} {}'.format(root, len(files)))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: I get the same error. Which Python version do you use?

Comment: @S.Kajmer: what version of Python are you using? That error is know to affect some early versions of Python. I've updated the answer to use explicitly named fields which should circumvent the problem.

Comment: @MostWanted: answer already updated to do that, and comment posted to same effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

print [(item[0], len(item[2])) for item in os.walk('/path') if item[2]]
```

It returns a list of tuples of folders/subfolders and files count in `/path`.

OR

```
import os

for item in os.walk('/path'):
    if item[2]:
        print item[0], len(item[2])
```

It prints folders/subfolders and files count in `/path`.

If you want try faster solution, then you had to try to combine:

```
os.scandir() # from python 3.5.2
```

iterate recursively and use:

```
from itertools import count

counter = count()
counter.next() # returns at first 0, next 1, 2, 3 ...

if counter.next() > 1000:
    print 'dir with file count over 1000' # and use continue in for loop
```

Maybe that will be faster, because I think in `os.walk` function are unnecessary things for you.

Comment: Please leave a comment.

Comment: This answers, very literally, the question asked by the OP in the first line of the question, however, it does not produce the output shown by the OP.

Comment: This counts the whole files. Please look at my example output.

Comment: Sure thing. Edited.

Comment: The time is good. I counted 178983 files from the path / in 7 seconds.

Comment: @S.Kajmer now it also prints it one by one.

Comment: @turkus Thanks it works. I add this line `if len(item[2]) > 1000:` and now it shows only folders with more than 1000 files. By the way, is there any function in python which automatically determine the output for example to 1000 entries? To reduce the run time?

Comment: On a server with many files it takes 13 minutes. I look for a very fast solution since 3 months :(

Comment: @S.Kajmer Let me think.

Comment: Do you use HDD or maybe SSD? Because in that case only one limit is drive. You HAVE TO calculate number of files and do the condition with 1000.

Comment: The server are running on a Virtual Disk (VMware).

Comment: @turkus How can I use os.scandir()? Can you post the complete program code? I'm very new in Python.

Comment: Any other solutions for Python 2.6.6 ? I can't install the new version some webserver use the old version of python. Any other solution in an other programming language? Bash, C++, ...

Comment: Of course you can ask in other programming languages, I can help only on Python.

Comment: For Python 2.6.6 you won't find anything better.